# How to organize classes when creating a java library

Tags: java, package, static-methods

I am creating a science library that contains methods for many branches of science and mathematics including calculus, statistics, physics and so on.  Right now I have the following set up:

[image]

In `maths`, `Calculus.java` and `Evaluation.java` are the only classes I want public, in which I will have my public static methods that are accessible everywhere in the project.

**Should I have more packages? More directories?  Will adding more make things more complicated/unusable?**  I tried creating more packages, but it forced me to make classes such as `BinaryOperation.java` `public`, which I do not want since a user of this library should not need to deal with a binary operator.

Methods I want available to the user(`public static`):

- `derive(String)`, `integrate(String)` in `Calculus.java`
- `evaluate(String, double)` in `Evaluation.java`

Comment: @ The "Primarily Opinion Based"-Voters: **No**. This question may in fact be "Too Broad", as the answer depends on the intended goals, but *depending* on the goals, there are clear pros and cons for the different solutions, and the use-case given in the question narrows down the points that should be relevant for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several degrees of freedom. They vary in how "clean" or "puristic" they are, how sustainable and maintainable, and how strongly a certain structure is enforced, from a technical point of view.

A pragmatic answer is simple: When users should see a class or interface, then make it `public`. Otherwise: Do **not** make it `public`.

This is very clean and very strong: Nobody can use a class that he is not supposed to use. The *JavaDoc* will by default generate the documentation for the public classes, which is exactly what you want.

It's important to realize that *once* something has been `public`, you can no longer simply move, remove, rename or structurally change that thing. Each of these changes will break client's code.

---

However, the point that you mentioned frequently occurs when applications/libraries become larger: There is a set of classes that should be shared among *all packages of the **library***, but still not be visible to the outside world - as in your case, the `maths.eval.BinaryOperation` class.

Some options that I see here are:

1. Place all classes that *use* the `BinaryOperation` class into one package. This is likely **not** a reasonable option, because they are otherwise unrelated, and only have the `BinaryOperation` as a (very low-level) cross-cutting concern. (However, it is "clean" and "strong" in the sense mentioned above)
2. Mark the `BinaryOperation` as something that should not be used by clients. You could place it, for example, into a package that is named like `...common.internal.implementation`, and clearly state in the JavaDoc that *"... this class is not supposed to be used by clients"*. This is neither clean nor strong. But it causes the least effort for you, and may thus be a reasonable trade-off.
3. Pull out the `BinaryOperation` into an own library. (Probably together with `UnaryOperation` and several other classes). This library could then be packaged as something like `common-operations.jar`. The users of your `math...` library will **only** rely on the main library. The fact that the main library depends on the "operations" library will not be visible *in the main library itself*. Tools like Maven help you to resolve these dependencies transparently for the user of your library. The severe drawback here: It places the burden to maintain this (public) "operations"-library on you.
4. Just for completeness: For "large scale" software development, there are additional solutions. For example, in the context of OSGi, you can define [access rules for packages](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/access_rules.htm)

<sub>An opinion: I'd go for option 2. or 3.</sub>

---

Side notes:

**Don't call your root package `maths`!** Everybody can create such a package (but nobody *should* create it). If you intend to create a library that is publicly available, then have a look at the [Package naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) : Your package name should be a "reversed domain name". So register, for example, the domain "defoification.com", and name your package `com.defoification.maths`. Everything else will lead to problems in the long run.

All this goes hand in hand with certain principles of API design and OOP in general. For example, some people advocate for a design that is very strict, in the sense that only interfaces should be `public`, and there should be no `public` classes for the actual data model at all. Also, the details of class design may have certain caveats. For example, the choice of modifiers for methods (if you have public classes). Methods should rarely be `public`, but rather `public final`, `protected final` or `protected abstract`, depending on who should be allowed to call or override it. More information about this (and many related topics) can be found in http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Main_Page and the corresponding "Practical API Design" book by Jaroslav Tulach, one of the main NetBeans authors.

Answer (score 1):

In the "real" world, the answer is: *it depends*.

There isn't "one" structure that can easily be deduced. How to slice and dice your application into "components", "modules", "libraries", packages very much depends on your requirements. When you are the only person working on this source code, go with something "simple" that helps *you* to write code. In a larger, "real" project, you would factor in many other aspects.

Just one example: there is [Conway's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law) that states

> organizations which design systems ... are constrained to produce designs which are copies of the communication structures of these organizations.

In other words: when you have two different teams work on the same thing, it might be wise to have them work on **different** packages. Or even on different "components" that make up your application/product.

My direct hints for you:

- in case you intend your code to be used by others, create a specific package that *only* contains the "public" elements. Keep your "internal" stuff separated
- your class names seem to indicate that one part of your project is about parsing expressions; to later work with those. Then a responsibility such as *parsing* for sure goes into its own package.
- so, the one paradigm that should guide you is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

But most imporantly: such things are subject to change - any decent IDE supports moving classes between packages nowadays. Thus the **key** thing to understand is: don't waste too much time to decide on the perfect directory structure **up front**.

Instead: observe the effects of your design decisions. And when you realize: "this approach isn't working for me" - then spent the time to *change* things. And: have other people *review* your work. 50% of learning is programming yourself - 150% is listening to experienced folks giving you feedback on your output.

Finally: if you are really interested in *learning* about this, I recommend to have a look into *Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#* by Robert Martin. That book describes **all** aspects of building a real world application; including questions such as "how do I *package* my product".

Comment: *"such things are subject to change"* - Maybe it's clear, but maybe this neglects one of the key points: You **cannot** change something that is `public`.

Comment: Very well depends. You can mark it deprecated today, and remove it next year. Or you provide such a great product that your users are willing to bite the bullet and accept incompatible changes. Never say never.

Comment: API changes are a source of headaches, and I'm with Josh Bloch here: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design . One can "soften" the transitions, by using `@Beta` (as in guava) until the first kinks are ironed out (based on feedback that can then already be gathered), and, if absolutely necessary, use `@Deprecated` and introduce a clear version-based deprecation model (hoping that it won't end with 50% `Beta` and 50% `Deprecated` ;-) ). However, the option of having a dedicated package, as in "math-api.jar", is indeed rather common, and worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the methods that are needed outside as public and rest of as private, still mark the class modifier as public only so that this could be extended down the line if needed. More packages dont hurt anyway as long as they are logical.

Comment: So you don't think it would hurt/be bad coding practice to make a class in the `maths` package public even though none of its methods are static?  In other words, the user will know about `public class BinaryOperator`, but would not have any methods accessible

Comment: @defoification its not necessary to have all the methods static'lly accessible in a public class. We can still have the public class for the extendibility so that the child classes in the other packages can extend its behaviour and member variables defined if any. In your case BinaryOperator class could be extended down the line in other packages and then enhance its behaviour. What say ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of other classes from `math` to package private by removing the `public` modifier. E.g. from

```
public class BinaryOperation
```

to

```
class BinaryOperation
```

The user of your library won't be able to have access to those classes, or their members. Of course, unless they create a package with the same name. Nothing you can do to stop people who really tries. ;)

Comment: I have it set up this way currently.  But I want to add folders to organize classes - Is it unconventional to make classes public even when I don't make any of its methods static (so that the user can't use any methods, even though they can still see the class)? For example (new package `eval`): `maths.eval.BinaryOperation` is visible to the user, but there is nothing he/she can do with it